# Is it possible to have a VariableSizedGridView with virtualization?

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) application. The mainpage template is a two GridView (2 grids per row) and the height of grid varies (one item might occupy one row and other might occupy two rows). The design is similar to the pinterest app (pin.it) except the varying height in pinterest app. I was able to achieve it using VariableSizedGridView and I did lazy loading as well. But I could find that there is no virtualization because of which the memory goes on increasing on scrolling down. Can you suggest me the how to achieve variable sized grid with virtualization like the pinterest app?

Please check the code below:

```
<local:VariableSizedGridView x:Name="samples"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding listofData}"
                        Margin="0,0,-24,0">
        <local:VariableSizedGridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="190" 
                                       ItemWidth="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ScreenWidthMultiplier}, ConverterParameter=1}"
                                                       Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:VariableSizedGridView.ItemsPanel>
        <local:VariableSizedGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <local:MainPageTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                        <local:MainPageTemplateSelector.BigTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="380" Background="White"
                                                      Margin="0,3,6,3">
                                    <Grid Margin="12" Background="Pink">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="250"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                                           Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Black">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Foreground="Red"                                                                   
                                                                   Margin="12 3 12 5"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>                                      
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:MainPageTemplateSelector.BigTemplate>

                        <local:MainPageTemplateSelector.SmallTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="190" Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ScreenWidthMultiplier}, ConverterParameter=1}"
                                        Background="Blue"              Margin="0,3,6,3">
                                    <Grid Margin="12" Background="Green">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                        <RowDefinition />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>                                        
                                    <Image Height="150"
                                                           Stretch="Fill"
                                                           Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Black">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                                                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                                   Margin="12 5 12 5"/>                                            
                                    </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:MainPageTemplateSelector.SmallTemplate>
                    </local:MainPageTemplateSelector>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:VariableSizedGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </local:VariableSizedGridView>
```

And the VariableSizedGridView

```
public class VariableSizedGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        dynamic model = item;
        try
        {
            element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, model.ColSpan);
            element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, model.RowSpan);
        }
        catch
        {
            element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpanProperty, 1);
            element.SetValue(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpanProperty, 1);
        }
        finally
        {
            element.SetValue(VerticalContentAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Stretch);
            element.SetValue(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
            base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        }
    }
```

Thank you,
Neenu